# strange issue with .htaccess redirect breaks if source path is the same name as a existing php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've noticed a strange situation that occurs when I try to create a mod-rewrite entry where the source path is also the same name as an existing php file in the same folder. See example

```
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ redirect.php?page=user&name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The issue is that I'm calling the directory "/users/" as the source path in the rule and if I also have a file in the root folder with the same name "users.php" then the rule above ends up pointing to that file instead of the page I want to redirect rule to point to (which is redirect.php in this case).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of Apache content negotiation.
To disable it, put this line in your htaccess (for example, before `RewriteEngine on` line)

```
Options -MultiViews
```